# Landsat 9 Image Collections are not producing any images from July 7th to the present. Why is this?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, landsat

I have a code that has been using the most recent Landsat 9 images from the last 48 hours, and since the 7th, none of my code has worked because there are no images to pull from Landsat image collections within the last two weeks or so.

[image: Code Example]

Comment: [Add the code as text please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

The USGS site which publishes Landsat images has been down for planned maintenance this weekend (and has been having problems in the last couple of weeks).

Once the images are available there, they will be copied into Earth Engine and be available to use.

Comment: I see, Thank you!